# How to get multiple values from the <img> element using JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an `<img>` element and all of its image data stored. I want to get one by one all of the data of image in jQuery

```
<img class="enent_inst" id="myImg" style="width:100%;" alt="<?php echo $events[$j]['title']; ?>" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/Event_gallary/<? php echo $events[$j]['event_image']; ?>" />
```

JS code:

```
$(document).on('click','#myImg',function(){
  var img = document.getElementById('myImg').attr( "alt" ); 
  alert(img);
};
```

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery and vanilla JS this way?!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `document.getElementById('myImg')` with `$(this)` to receive the element by jQuery, as you already use it ...

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myImg', function() {
  var img = $(this).attr("alt");
  alert(img);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="enent_inst" id="myImg" style="width:100%;" alt="test" src="" />
```

Answer (score -1):

change `attr` to `getAttribute`

or use jQuery:

```
var img = $('#myImg').attr( "alt" );
```